# Как сейчас возможно сделать зеркало сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, зеркало

Как сейчас возможно сделать зеркало сайта?
Интересуют методы: PHP, HTML, Apache proxy, JavaScript.
Будет ли возможен переход по внутренним ссылкам, но необходимо, чтобы домен при этом оставался мой?

Answer (score 1):

#### Способ 1:

Возьмите исходники и запустите на другом сервере.

#### Способ 2:

Сделайте прокси сервер, который будет принимать запрос от клиента, отправлять его на оригинальный сервер, заменять ссылки в ответе и отдавать изменённый ответ клиенту.

В `nginx` есть модуль `ngx_http_sub_module` как раз для таких целей:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://original.ru;
    sub_filter "original.ru" "mirror.ru";
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```